# Bash [ $k -eq 2  || keypressed -eq "ctrl+alt+backspace"];

Tags: bash

Добрый день. Есть скрипт, который запускает rdp коннект, но при пропадании сети соединение зависает. Есть ли возможность указать ожидание какого либо сочетания клавиш для закрытия программы, типа [ $k -eq 2  || keypressed -eq "ctrl+alt+backspace"];Сам скрипт: (k=0 && until [ $k -eq 2 ]; do xfreerdp -z -f -a 16 -x 100 -d comp.local -u user 99.99.99.99; $k=${?}; done && gdm-control --shutdown && openbox --exit) &

Comment: А в чем суть что именно вы делаете, зачем вам в цикле два запуска rdp?

Comment: Задача создать хот-кей для прерывания работы freerdp

Comment: Если оно в фокусе , Alt-F4 , не ?

Comment: Не :) Просто зависает при пропадании сети и только руками через kill -9 убить можно

Comment: Ну наверняка в вашем дистре есть хот кеи, повесьте на него killall -9 xfreerdp .

Comment: Всем спасибо. Добавил в скрипт setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp и все отлично стало